# Submitting a dynamic update to updatelistitems web service without managed code

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

I have a browser-enabled form written with Infopath 2007.  I am unable to use managed code.

I would like to create a new Sharepoint 2007 list item using the updatelistitems() webservice.

I can do this if I create a CAML template and use the template to create a "receive" secondary data connection.  The newly created data connection is then used as the update parameter when accessing the updatelistitems() webservice in the "submit" data connection.

However, I would like the user to be able to provide some of the new data using a drop-down list box.  However, I can't figure out how to include the selected item in the dropdown box in the update submission.

I tried dynamically constructing a batch statement, putting it in a text box, and using this as the update CAML XML, but I get a message indicating that there was an error in the update.

How do I dynamically construct a batch statement and submit to updatelistitem without using managed code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can't use managed code, you should be able to use Javascript on a browser enabled form.  Most of the samples include javascript code to do validation and calculations.  you should be able to something similar for your call to the webservice.